# Wrangling network adjacency data in jq: dictionary to array

Tags: json, jq, adjacency-matrix, data-wrangling

I have graph data in JSON and would like to massage it a bit so that:

```
{"1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"2": [3, 4, 7]}
```

Becomes

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 7]
```

Is it possible using **jq**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
to_entries | map([[.key|tonumber],.value] | combinations) | .[]
```

[`combinations`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#combinations,combinations(n)) takes an array of two arrays as input and outputs an array of the combinations of the elements of the two input arrays. In our case we want to provide it with an array that contains the key and the value arrays.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/aKd6zuLqkB).

Answer (score 0):

Using an elementary approach here produces an efficient solution:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k
| .[$k][] as $v
| [$k|tonumber] + [$v]
```